# A "new" formula relating the quotients of the upper central series, method of proof and background information

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abstract-algebra

For a finite group $G$ the upper central series is defined inductively by 
$$
 Z_1(G) := Z(G), \qquad Z_{i+1}(G) / Z_i(G) = Z( G / Z_i(G) ).
$$
Now I am interested in generalising this formula, i.e. for $j > i$ do we have
$$
 Z_j(G) / Z_i(G) = Z_{j - i}( G / Z_i(G) ).
$$
Of course for $j = i + 1$ this is just the definition.

I have two proofs, the first is by direct computation, i.e. using
$$
 Z_{i+1}(G) = \{ x \in G : [x,y] \in Z_i(G) \mbox{ for all } y \in G \}.
$$
Suppose inductively that $Z_{j-1}(G)/Z_i(G) = Z_{(j-1)-i}(G/Z_i(G))$ and $j > i+1$,
then
\begin{align*}
 xZ_i(G) \in Z_j(G) / Z_i(G) 
  & \Leftrightarrow x \in Z_j(G) \\
  & \Leftrightarrow \forall y \in G : [x,y] \in Z_{j-1}(G) \\
  & \Leftrightarrow \forall y \in G : [x,y]Z_i(G) \in Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) \\
  & \Leftrightarrow \forall y \in G : [x,y]Z_i(G) \in Z_{(j-1)-i}(G / Z_i(G)) \\
  & \Leftrightarrow \forall y \in G : [xZ_i(G), yZ_i(G)] \in Z_{(j-1)-i}(G / Z_i(G)) \\
  & \Leftrightarrow xZ_i(G) \in Z_{j-1}( G / Z_i(G) ).
\end{align*}
But I do not like that approach. As for subgroup series, using properties of subgroups like the Dedekind identity or isomorphism theorem are preferable, as they lead more easily to generalisations for other subgroup series, and I guess it might be possible to give such a proof here, without breaking it down to computing with commutators.

I tried, and arrived at a second proof. Suppose inductively that for $j > i + 1$
$$
 Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) = Z_{(j-1)-i}( G / Z_i(G) )
$$
then by taking the quotient of both sides of the formula we want to prove, the isomorphism theorems and using the definition for $j = i + 1$
$$
 (Z_j(G) / Z_i(G)) / ( Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) ) \cong Z_j(G) / Z_{j-1}(G) = Z(G / Z_{j-1}(G)) 
$$
and by induction hypothesis and using the definition
\begin{align*}
 Z_{j-i}( G / Z_i(G) ) / Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G)
  & = Z_{j-i}( G / Z_i(G) ) / Z_{(j-1)-i}( G / Z_i(G) ) \\
  & = Z( ( G / Z_i(G) ) / Z_{(j-1)-i}( G / Z_i(G) ) ) \\
  & = Z( G / Z_i(G) / ( Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) ) )  \\
\end{align*}
and as $G / Z_i(G) / ( Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G)) \cong G / Z_{j-1}(G)$ we have
$$
 Z(G / Z_i(G) / ( Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) ) ) ) \cong Z( G / Z_{j-1}(G) ).
$$
So we have that both subgroups
$$
 ( Z_j(G) / Z_i(G) ) / ( Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) )
$$
and
$$
 Z_{j-i}( G / Z_i(G) ) / Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G)
$$
are isomorphic to the same group, so in general we just get that they are isomorphic. But to conclude $(Z_j(G) / Z_i(G)) = Z_{j-i}( G / Z_i(G) )$, i.e. that their inverse images under the quotient are equal, we need more than isomorphism, we need equality. Looking at the proof of the isomorphism theorems, we see that a map realising the mentioned isomorphisms is $\varphi : G / Z_i(G) \to G / Z_{j-1}(G)$ with
$$
 xZ_i(G) \mapsto xZ_{j-1}(G).
$$
Then the map $\overline \varphi(x \cdot \mbox{ker}(\varphi)) := \varphi(x)$
with $x \in G / Z_i(G)$ gives the isomorphism, and as
$$
 \overline{\varphi}( (Z_j(G) / Z_i(G)) / (Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) ) )
 = \overline{\varphi}( Z_{j-i}( G / Z_i(G) ) / Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) ) 
$$
and as $\overline{\varphi}$ is an isomorphism we have
$$
 (Z_j(G) / Z_i(G)) / (Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G) )
 = Z_{j-i}( G / Z_i(G) ) / Z_{j-1}(G) / Z_i(G)
$$
hence $Z_j(G) / Z_i(G) = Z_{j-i}( G / Z_i(G) )$.

Okay, both proofs make me at least confident that the formula holds. But I do not like them both. The first is commutator computation, which I guess could be avoided by reasoning on the "higher level" of the subgroup series, in the other a specific map used in the proof of the isomorphism theorem is involved, which also takes some flavour of generality as the isomorphism theorem are not used plainly, but with respect to some arbitrary choice, i.e. a map realising the stated isomorphisms.

So is there any proof of this formula which does not has these drawbacks? I also looked up the literature, but I nowhere found this formula. So maybe most authors consider it to trivial to state or do not mind it, I do not know but at least if it is trivial there must be some (preferable elegant) short proof. So specifically I am asking about an elegant proof of this formula, and maybe some background information. Is it known, used somewhere?

Comment: This property seems clear from the fact that (as the name suggests), the upper central series is the fastest rising central series. If  the quickest route from $A$ to $B$ takes you through point $C$, then the quickest route from $C$ to $B$ must be the same as it when you are going all the way from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But could you make this more formal?

Comment: In any case it seems more suitable for Math StackExchange.

Comment: Ok, should I delete and reopen there, or could it moved automatically to math.SE without deleting comments?

Comment: I think that you are making moderately straightforward arguments very hard to read, by having so many subscripts, etc. Everything depends on the following general result. Let $1 \le A \le B \le C \le G$ with $A,B,C$ all normal in $G$. Then $C/B \le Z(G/B) \Leftrightarrow (C/A)/(B/A) \le Z((G/A)/(B/A))$.  This is elementary, and there are several straightforward proofs. My preferred proof (but probably not yours) would be use the   group isomorphism theorems for groups with operators. It follows from $C/B \cong (C/A)/(B/A)$ under the operation of conjugation by $G$.